# NameError: name '' is not defined Python

Tags: python-3.x, undefined, nameerror

i would like to make a blackjack algorithm and i have almost finished the code. Although i get all the time the error NameError: name 'pointCoint' is not defined. I found out on the internet that i should change raw_input into input due to the python version 3.6 which i am using. Can somebody help me and have a look at my code whether i am missing something? dealerCount = pointCoint(dealer)
NameError: name 'pointCoint' is not defined

Thanks

Comment: Fix your indentation, indicate where the error is occurring and strip your code down to a minimal example.

Comment: There are lots of errors in this code but nothing that is named "pointCoint". In which line does the error occur?

Comment: line 49, dealerCount = pointCoint(dealer)

Comment: `pointCoint` != `pointCount`

Comment: @userpython1 
Do not delete your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a function called `pointCount(...)`, not `pointCoint`. Change `pointCoint` to `pointCount`.

Complete code:

```
from random import shuffle

def deck():
    deck = []
    for suit in ['H', 'D', 'S', 'C']:
        for rank in ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']:
            deck.append(suit+rank)
    shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def pointCount(myCards):
    myCount = 0
    aceCount = 0
    for i in myCards:
        if(i[1] == 'J' or i[1] == 'Q' or i[1] == 'K' or i[1] == 'T'):
            myCount += 10
        elif(i[1] != 'A'):
            myCount += int(i[1])
        else:
            aceCount += 1

    if(aceCount == 1 and myCount >= 10):
        myCount += 11
    elif(aceCount != 0):
        myCount += 1

    return myCount

def createPlayingHands(myDeck):
    dealerHand = []
    playerHand = []
    dealerHand.append(myDeck.pop())
    dealerHand.append(myDeck.pop())
    playerHand.append(myDeck.pop())
    playerHand.append(myDeck.pop())

    while(pointCount(dealerHand) <= 16):
        dealerHand.append(myDeck.pop())

    return [dealerHand, playerHand]

game = ""
myDeck = deck()
hands = createPlayingHands(myDeck)
dealer = hands[0]
player = hands[1]

while(game != "exit"):
    dealerCount = pointCount(dealer)
    playerCount = pointCount(player)
    print("Dealer has:")
    print(dealer[0])

    print("Player1, you have:")
    print(player)

    if(playerCount == 21):
        print("Blackjack Player wins")
        break
    elif(playerCount > 21):
        print("player Busts with " + str(playerCount) + "points")
        break
    elif(playerCount > 21):
        print("Dealer Busts with " + str(dealerCount) + "points")
        break

    game = input("What would you like to do? M: Hit me, S: Stand? ")

    if(game == 'H'):
        player.append(myDeck.pop())
    elif(playerCount > dealerCount):
        print("Player wins with " + str(playerCount) + "points")
        print("Dealer has: " + str(dealer) + "or" + str(dealerCount) + "points")
        break
    else:
        print("Dealer wins")
        print("Dealer has: " + str(dealer) + "or" + str(dealerCount) + "points")
        break
```